# Run OptaPlanner Project job scheduling using my own data but not get result

Tags: java, optaplanner

I want to resolve a job schedule problem with OptaPlanner Project job scheduling with my own data file:

> ---
>
> file with basedata            : J1206_.BAS
>    initial value random generator: 1430051105
>
> ---
>
> projects                      :  1
>    jobs (incl. supersource/sink ):  22
>    horizon                       :  1233
>    RESOURCES
>      - renewable                 :  5   R
>      - nonrenewable              :  0   N
>      - doubly constrained        :  0   D
>
> ---
>
> PROJECT INFORMATION:
>    pronr.  #jobs rel.date duedate tardcost  MPM-Time
>        1    20      0      100      100      100
>
> ---
>
> PRECEDENCE RELATIONS:
>    jobnr.    #modes  #successors   successors
>       1        1          6           2   4   7 12  17  19
>       2        1          1           3
>       3        1          1           6
>       4        1          1           5
>       5        1          1           6
>       6        1          1          22
>       7        1          1           8
>       8        1          2           9 10
>       9        1          1          11
>      10        1          1          11
>      11        1          1          22
>      12        1          2          13 14
>      13        1          1          15
>      14        1          1          15
>      15        1          1          16
>      16        1          1          22
>      17        1          1          18
>      18        1          1          20
>      19        1          1          20
>      20        1          1          21
>      21        1          1          22
>      22        1          0
>
> ---
>
> REQUESTS/DURATIONS:
>    jobnr. mode duration  R1  R2  R3  R4  R5
>
> ---
>
> 1      1     0       0    0    0    0      0
>      2      1    10       2    0    2    1      0
>      3      1     8       0    1    0    2      5
>      4      1    20       1    0    2    0      0
>      5      1     4       0    0    0    3      5
>      6      1     8       0    2    0    0      2
>      7      1     4       0    2    1    0      0
>      8      1    10       2    0    2    0      0
>      9      1     6       1    0    0    2      5
>     10      1    12       0    1    0    0      2
>     11      1     5       0    0    0    3      0
>     12      1    22       1    0    0    0      0
>     13      1    13       2    2    0    0      0
>     14      1     4       0    0    2    3      0
>     15      1    10       0    0    0    1      4
>     16      1     8       1    0    0    1      3
>     17      1     2       0    0    0    1      2
>     18      1    16       2    3    0    0      0
>     19      1    25       1    0    2    0      0
>     20      1     8       0    2    0    3      0
>     21      1     2       0    3    0    0      6
>     22      1     0       0    0    0    0  0
>
> ---
>
> RESOURCEAVAILABILITIES:
>      R1  R2  R3  R4  R5
>        3    4    2  3   6
>
> ---

It is one project data file organized by single mode.And i also have change the project list file as below:

> 1
>    0
>    100
>    filepath.mm
>    5
>    3  4  2  3  6

It generates a maximize total time  86 by OptaPlanner Project Job Scheduling but  not 83 which is generated by CPLEX. [my optaPlanner result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZeZ5.gif)

Are there any errors in my file?

Comment: How long did you run? The configuration currently in the project job scheduling example uses a pretty heavy entityTabuRatio, which works better on bigger instances.  For small instances like this, the CPLEX approach can be more efficient. This changes when scaling up to medium or big datasets.

Comment: It doesn't generate the best solution after one hour running with no stop. This total time is the second number accored when i run it,after that i hasn't get more high score any more.